# Invoke xacro macro in a launch file

Tags: ros-humble, xacro

I've been creating this stand alone urdf.xacro file to enact my macros. Is there a way to invoke/call a xacro macro from a python launch file and pass parameters? I've provided the file below. I'm using ROS 2 Humble.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro" name="pxxls_assembly">
    
    <xacro:include filename="$(find interbotix_xsturret_descriptions)/urdf/pxxls.urdf.xacro"
      ns="interbotix" />
    <xacro:interbotix.pxxls robot_name="pxxls" base_link_frame="base_link" />

</robot>
```

......

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics*, Yato. When you ask, "Is there a way to do this," what are you asking about? Is there a way to do... what? Could you please *edit your question* to clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: You can `xacro.process_file(urdf_file, mappings={'robot_name': ''}).toxml()` to pass in parameters to a urdf.